# Interpolating ERB as an HTML value attribute (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, parameters

I am attempting to pass data as params in a hidden input tag's **value** attribute:

```
<input name="quote[destination]" value= <%= "#{quote["InboundLeg"]["OriginCity"]}" %> type="hidden" />
```

When the form is submitted, the params contains the first word of the string being interpolated and drops everything after the first space.

If I decide to pass through an ordinary string to params through value like so:

```
<input name="quote[destination]" value= "foo bar buzz" type="hidden" />
```

the entirety of the string passes through unlike the former case. Can anyone shed some light on why this may be and some possible solutions?

Comment: Aside from just memorising the answers below, you need to learn how to debug your own code. Right click --> Inspect element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that line to:

```
<input name="quote[destination]" value="<%= quote["InboundLeg"]["OriginCity"] %>" type="hidden" />
```

Note that the quotes are outside of the ERB statement.

Or you might want to use the `hidden_field_tag` form helper which creates such hidden input fields and reads nicer:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'quote[destination]', quote["InboundLeg"]["OriginCity"] %>
```

I would always use a helper if I have a choice because IMHO is a bad practice to mix HTML and ERB like in the first example.

Comment: Using a form helper is the way to go. Besides shortening the code it also ensures valid markup and properly escaped values.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your input tag with

```
<input name="quote[destination]" value= "<%= quote['InboundLeg']['OriginCity'] %>" type="hidden" />
```

You have to apply quotes to the value